# Dockers work on Linux box but not on Windows box

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, gunicorn

My dockers work great on a Linux box.  Using similar docker, docker-compose, and configuration files on my windows laptop, they do not.

I get a 502 Bad Gateway error when I browse to 127.0.0.1:1337.  From docker logs pbnginx I get:

```
172.20.0.1 - - [08/Oct/2020:20:32:04 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36" "-"
172.20.0.1 - - [08/Oct/2020:20:33:12 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36" "-"
2020/10/08 20:33:12 [error] 30#30: *2 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.20.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.20.0.2:6060/", host: "localhost:1337"
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD . /code/
RUN chmod -R 755 /code
RUN useradd -m user
RUN chmod 777 /home/user
USER user
ENV PORT 7000
EXPOSE 7000
CMD ["gunicorn", "PB_Django.wsgi:application", "--config", "docker/pb_django/gunicorn.conf", "--keep-alive", "600"]
```

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  web:
      build:
          context: ../..
          dockerfile: docker/pb_django/Dockerfile
      image: pbdjango  
      container_name: pbdjango
      expose:
        - "7000"
      networks:
        - cieenetwork
      external_links:
        - stanfordcorenlp
  nginx:
      build: ./nginx
      image: pbnginx  
      container_name: pbnginx
      ports:
        - "1337:80"
      depends_on:
        - web
      networks:
        - cieenetwork
networks:
  cieenetwork:
    external: true
```

My nginx Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:alpine

RUN rm -f /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY static_cdn /static
```

My nginx.conf file:

```
upstream pb_django {
    server web:7000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    root /;

    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://pb_django/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_read_timeout 10m;
        proxy_connect_timeout 10m;
        client_max_body_size 700m;
    }

    location /static/ {
    }
}
```

My gunicorn.conf is:

```
bind = "0.0.0.0:7000"
timeout = 10000
```

docker ps -a shows:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES 
1b4e4d92b259        pbnginx             "/docker-entrypoint.…"   28 minutes ago      Up 28 minutes       0.0.0.0:1337->80/tcp     pbnginx 
c332c8e378e1        pbdjango            "gunicorn PB_Django.…"   28 minutes ago      Up 28 minutes       7000/tcp                 pbdjango 
1989d9a75c0d        stanfordcorenlp     "/bin/sh -c 'java -j…"   17 hours ago        Up 17 hours         0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp   stanfordcorenlp
```

docker network inspect cieenetwork shows:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "cieenetwork",
        "Id": "a58547f1d257eae4880f5411482bb33be4534a4299e55b0e40780e3f6679f521",
        "Created": "2020-09-30T17:49:38.9145072Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.20.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.20.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "1989d9a75c0d8722a89a879d57d5c2d454507ff43f3b4b79742469556d48b387": {
                "Name": "stanfordcorenlp",
                "EndpointID": "c8aff59b96aa2816daee7cf4e82b9d894a56d8870be935ac28c1b1754eb62aed",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "1b4e4d92b2597077027bbce9f8aa22a137de581592c58d7dc0204f452ce7e2ca": {
                "Name": "pbnginx",
                "EndpointID": "1f3c78aa73463610d166d3ba10792e095bee76ace3b29c1e81da567456dacdd1",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "c332c8e378e192f661ebb17f6b8ee9a88c47c76355e9a2acc4ecc34a9687a1de": {
                "Name": "pbdjango",
                "EndpointID": "c78c8d3e92472191f24f2c6bcc7108038a754bb5f933a49f59bd4e6243d1295e",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though, `docker inspect pbdjango` reported that OOMKIlled is false (Killed due to Out of memory), I increased the memory from 2 to 8 GB on docker desktop and my app worked properly with the above configurations.  Thanks to all who took the time to look at this post.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at "[Quickstart: Compose and Django](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/)", try, for testing, the note:

> On certain platforms (Windows 10), you might need to edit ALLOWED_HOSTS inside `settings.py` and add your Docker host name or IP address to the list.
> For demo purposes, you can set the value to:
>
> ```
> ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
> ```
>
> This value is not safe for production usage
> Refer to the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts) for more information.

Check also if you see any difference with "[Dockerizing Django with Postgres, Gunicorn, and Nginx](https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/)".